# Select lines not containing phrase

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have several lines win one word in each in my Notepad++. How to select all words not not containing `Set` ant `Get` phrase.

```
SetBlaBla1
BlaGetBla2
BlaBla3
```

Result should be `BlaBla3`

Comment: You could select (mark) all lines that contain `Get` or `Set` then invert the marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try negative look-ahead, something like this:

```
^((?!Set|Get).)*$
```